# Encrypting connection strings from Global.asax fails when run from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the following method to encrypt the connection strings in my web.config:

```
public static void EncryptConnectionString()
{
    var section = GetConfigSection();

    if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected) return;

    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
    section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
    section.CurrentConfiguration.Save();

}

private static ConnectionStringsSection GetConfigSection()
{
    var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    var section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
    if (section.ElementInformation.IsLocked || section.SectionInformation.IsLocked) return null;

    return section as ConnectionStringsSection;
}
```

- I placed a call to this method in Global.asax's `Application_Start()` method
- When running locally, the method works, I can see the connection strings become encrypted.
- When running from server, the method doesn't work. I run the app, and the web.config on server's connection strings remain unencrypted.
- Manually calling the method elsewhere seems to cause it work. If I call it from the app's HomeController I can see that the connection strings have been encrypted.
- Other methods in Global.asax's `Application_Start()` appear to work, as I can see my registered bundles being used.

So why wouldn't calling this method, which edits the web.config, work when calling from `Application_Start()`?

Answer (score 0):

Application_Start is called when the application is first started or, more specifically, when the application receives the first request. Try hitting the Home Controller and have it do nothing, then check if the web.config gets encrypted.